# Downloading Image in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to download the image from UI in angular 4. So far, i've applied the following code to download the image:

```
DownloadImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
imageUrl = this.ImagePath + imageUrl;
this.Service.GetImage(imageUrl, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })

  .map(res => {
    return new Blob([res._body], {
      type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
    });
  })
  .map(blob => {
    var urlCreator = window.URL;
    return 
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
  })
 }
```

Following the "GetImage" function:

```
GetImage(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(url, this.addWithImage(options)).map((res) => res.json());
}

private addWithImage(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    // ensure request options and headers are not null
    options = options || new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = options.headers || new Headers();

    // add authorization header with token
    const token = 'XXXXXXXX';
    if (token) {
        options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    }
    return options;
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will work and i can't test it now, but give it a try:

```
DownloadImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
 imageUrl = this.ImagePath + imageUrl;
 var link = document.createElement("a");
 link.setAttribute("href", imageUrl);
 link.setAttribute("download", 'coolNameForTheFile.jpg');
 link.innerText = "click";
 link.click();
}
```

Try it in Chrome first. I had problems with it in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is opening the file in the same window. I don't want to open it.